# WordPress template using React. Incorrect chars

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, axios

I am creating a WordPress template, using React. I have a WP Post that looks perfect in DB. To retrieve data from the server I use Axios, using the new API feature included in WordPress.

This is how the title looks in the DB:

```
Hello world! I'm leaving
```

This is the code I use to retrieve the title from DB:

```
axios.get('/paintings-project/wp-json/wp/v2/posts').then(
    function(response){
        self.setState({posts: response.data})
    }
);
```

This is how the post title looks when rendered:

```
Hello world! I&#8217;m leaving
```

The char ' is escaped, and the backslash used for escaping is encoded.

On the other hand, when rendering HTML content from the post, the HTML appears as a string, instead of rendered as HTML. Like this:

`<h1>Welcome&#8217; to WordPress&#8217;.</h1> <p><strong>This is your first
post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</strong></p> <p>&nbsp;</p>`

I expected the WordPress APIs would work straight without need of special encoding / decoding in BE or FE. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React doesn't allow you to render strings as HTML in that way. You're going to have to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)) to render your HTML string in your component.

Something like:

```js
renderStr() {
  return {__html: this.state.dataToRender};
},

render() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={renderStr()} />;
}
```

Bear in mind, as the attribute name suggests, you'll want to make sure that the HTML you're rendering is safe. If it's coming from user input, make sure to sanitize the input before storing/rendering it or you can expose yourself and others to security risks. You can use an NPM dependency like [sanitizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitizer) or [sanitize-html](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html), or you can write a function to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I will investigate this sanitizer tools. Anyway, I guess this is something that will happen to any WP single page Theme. I could not find any mention to this issue in the documentation.

Comment: @jdominguez Glad to hear it! Please check my reply as the answer so others can know it worked if they have a similar issue.